# UI carousel view in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net-core, carousel, maui

[image]

Referring to the screenshot as a reference, I am stuck with this design. How should I design it in .NET MAUI ? Maui should have sample of single item as a carousel view. And the screenshot shows multiple items. Should I use grids with frames or what, please advice. Thanks.

I try carousel view with single items and the same is also presented in example code on internet. Should I miss something or their are any intercepted event which I have to trigger to mimic the outcome as presented in the screenshot.

Comment: I would use [Flex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/flexlayout?view=net-maui-8.0) with and Icon and Image and bindable layouts if needed, for the swiping part Carousel should work ideally

Answer (score -1):

Below code is related  carousel.
You can change the image according your requirement.

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">

            <img src="https://media.zigcdn.com/media/content/2023/Aug/64dcac7c1591e_720x540.jpg" style="height: 570px" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Hyundai/Exter/9482/1684926596004/headlight-43.jpg" style="height: 570px" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Hyundai/Exter/9482/1684926596004/exterior-image-164.jpg" style="height: 570px" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's HTML, MAUI uses XAML. Unless the OP wants to use MAUI Blazor, this is not useful.